# Why does spring-boot-3 give javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, spring-boot

When I ran spring-boot-2.7, there is no issue. However when I changed code and tailored it to spring-boot-3.0, there is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest

Could someone help me to download the source code and run on your computer? After run it, and you click "Login using Facebook", you will see the exception.
https://github.com/chuangtc/spring-boot-3.0-security-social-login

I tried adding jarkarta servlet api 6.0, but the exception is still there.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You don't have to add jakarta servlet api 6.0 into the `pom.xml`.
According to documentation [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-3.0-Migration-Guide#Jakarta-EE), it is already included.

In your code whichever is using `javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest`, you need to change the `javax` to `jakarta`.

So the whole line will be something like this:
`import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest`

I faced this error before when I upgrade my service as well and I solved it using this way. Maybe you can try it.

[EDIT]

I see that one of your dependency is using the `javax.servlet`:
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.social/spring-social-facebook/2.0.3.RELEASE

And following this github, it seems this packages is no longer actively maintained and being archived, so it is likely they do not upgrade for Spring Boot 3.

I would recommend find other ways to work on the social login for Facebook, maybe you can try this way?

https://www.codejava.net/frameworks/spring-boot/social-login-with-facebook-example

Comment: In my code, there is no servlet.http.HttpServletRequest

Comment: I checked your source code and I think this dependency is using the `javax.servlet`: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.social/spring-social-facebook/2.0.3.RELEASE

The `Provided Dependency` is showing `javax.servlet`, so when you run your apps, this dependency will be used.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I made it work for spring-boot-3.0
https://chuangtc.com/Java/spring-boot-30-facebook-login.php

Comment: I'm glad it helps! If it is okay please marked it as answer :)

Comment: Saved may day! I would have never guessed that. But you need to include jakarta.servlet-api.

Comment: it worked, commented javax.servlet.api dependecy and changed all import javax.persistence. to jakarta.persistence

Comment: In my case, I got this issue because I added the Swagger dependencies, but in the exception stack, I did not find it because of these Swagger APIs. How did you troubleshoot that the spring boot 3.0 doesn't come with javax.servlet.httpservlet and the swagger (or someother api) expecting this API. please clarify

Answer (score 3):

In my case I had the following dependencies:

```
implementation "io.springfox:springfox-swagger2"
implementation "io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui"
```

Which apparently somehow depended on the old api, because commenting them solved the issue.

Comment: How did you come to know that because of these dependencies, only you got that issue? or it's just a hit-and-run.?

Answer (score 0):

You can also try adding new dependencies as follows. With the below dependencies I was able to retain javax.servlet class.

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2</version>
  </dependency> 
  <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```